# C# How to subtract using a textbox on each click and show in another textbox

Tags: c#

I am wanting to subtract each time I click the subtract button, right now all it does is subtract it once. I guess it always sees the needed value as 4000 which is why it doesn't subtract it more than once because each click it retrieves the initial needed value.

```
int needed = 4000;
private void subtractBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Subtract = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Subtract.Text);
        remaining = needed - Subtract;
        textBox_Remaining.Text = remaining.ToString();

        if (remaining <=0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hey it's done");
        }
    }
```

For anyone who is as dumb as me here is the final code

```
private void subtractBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Subtract = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Subtract.Text);

        remaining = needed - Subtract;
        needed = remaining;


        textBox_Remaining.Text = remaining.ToString();

        if (remaining <=0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hey it's done");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't ever change the `needed` field. What makes you think the code would do anything different from what it does now? Why don't you just copy your new value back into the `needed` field?

Comment: it could be anything and will most likely be set by the user. it's just set for now.  and I don't know what you mean by this "Why don't you just copy your new value back into the needed field"

Comment: _"it could be anything and will most likely be set by the user. it's just set for now"_ -- for the purposes of this question, the only thing that matter is _now_. You don't appear to have made any attempt whatsoever to modify your program so that the initial value subtracted from is adjusted to account for previous subtractions. It's not possible to help you, unless we know why it is you can't figure this out yourself (someone may, and probably will, just post code that works, but that won't help you understand how to do it correctly the next time).

Comment: _"I don't know what you mean..."_ -- please be more specific. The words I wrote seem clear to me. Explain which part or parts of the sentence I wrote you don't understand, and why you don't understand it. Do you not know how to copy the value from one variable to another? Do you not know what I mean by "the needed field"? Something else?

Comment: what you are talking about is setting a new value for needed to the current value on click of remaining, so unless i initially set remaining to the value of needed and then set remaining -= Subtract   ... I guess I just don't understand...

Comment: Peter Duniho is right. Your needed variable will not change unless you set needed value to your result or should i say to "remaining".

Comment: Just add `needed = remaining` at the end, perhaps as `else` after the if statement,

Comment: bloody hell
 remaining = needed - Subtract;
            needed = remaining;

Comment: I got it now, I am just fried from staring at code all day trying to learn this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private void subtractBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Subtract = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Subtract.Text);
    remaining = needed - Subtract;
    needed = remaining;
    textBox_Remaining.Text = remaining.ToString();

    if (remaining <=0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey it's done");
    }
}
```